# Multidimensional array of gtkwidgets

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, gtk

Is it possible to create a multidimensional array of gtkwidgets? Specifically something like this:

```
mywidgetlist[2]["title"];
```

Or should I be doing this in a different way? How would I do this?

Basically I have a number of "widgets" (Loaded from gtkbuilder) composed of smaller widgets and I want to be able to change certain values, so this array setup seems preferable.

Is there another way of doing this (Other than actually coding a complete widget using signals etc and placing them in a simple array?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you cannot use a string to index into an array. Or, strictly speaking you can, but it's almost never what you want to do.

For C solution using glib (handy if you already use GTK+), consider a single-dimensional array of `GHashTable` pointers.

Comment: Well I don't really need the string but my main problem is with the multidimensional part. Now that I think of it, could I attach a ListView model to it via signals somehow?